# Applying Gaussian blur/filter to an image in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, imagefilter

I am using the Gaussian function from `openCV` to make my image blur/filter and to retrieve the values of the pixels of an image, before and after the blur is applied on it.

problem is there is no difference in pixel values between image without blur and with blur, but image display after the Gaussian blur is actually blurred and kernel matrix is of size 3*3. it would be surely appreciated, if anyone can solve this problem,thanks in advance, here is my code.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  Mat image = imread("C:/santhu/bitmap.bmp");
  int rows=image.rows;
  int cols=image.cols;

  if (image.empty()) 
    {
      cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

  cout<<"the output for matrix of pixels";

  //code to access pixel values of an image
  cout<<"\nbefore blur";
  for (int i = 0; i <rows; i++)
    {
      Vec3b *ptr = image.ptr<Vec3b>(i);

      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {   
      Vec3b pixel = ptr[j];
      //cout<<pixel<<"\t";
        }
      cout<<"\n";
    }

  imshow("Image", image);//displaying image
  waitKey(0);

  Mat image1=image.clone();//cloning image

  GaussianBlur( image, image1, Size( 7, 7), 0, 0 );//applying Gaussian filter 


  cout<<"\nafter blur";

  //code to access pixel values of an image
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
      Vec3b *ptr = image1.ptr<Vec3b>(i);

      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {   
      Vec3b pixel = ptr[j];
      //cout<<pixel<<"\t";
        }
      cout<<"\n";
    }


  imshow("image1:",image1);//displaying image1
  waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Your code runs fine here, just try with another image.

Comment: A better approach would be to check the **difference image** instead of each pixel.

Comment: @Haris, i know my code runs fine,when i try to compare the pixel values of both image[i have printed on console],with blur and before blurring is applied on it,they had the same pixel values.how it can be pos?

Comment: and hey @scap3y difference image means, u mean it  in the sense of pixels difference between two images ,right?

Comment: Yes, just do `image_3 = image_1 - image_2` and see what the result is. If there is a type mismatch in the images, then it will show up here.

Comment: @scap3y, i have checked every pixel of both images,it's a same,so if i apply and check difference,then result is surely be zero.

Comment: @Santhosh Can you show your image ?

Comment: u can get image here ,https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjrigcwsionvhb4/bitmap.bmp.,but i have tried for many images,might be, we may have to pass reference of image  into the Gaussian filter function.

Comment: is this a roundoff issue.  If color-changes aren't big, like what happens in high resolution, then maybe roundoff plus blur equals initial?  Except at sharp edges where a single pixel difference might be hard to see?